# How to send non-normalized/unclamped values to GLSL shader using opengl textures?

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping, heightmap

I am trying to send an array of float values(height map) to GLSL as a GL_TEXTURE_2D.  While I have the samplers set right, the issue comes from the clamping that happens when I upload the texture using glTexImage2D().

```
  glGenTextures(1, &_idnewTID);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _idnewTID);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, regMesh._cols, regMesh._rows, 0, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, regMesh._heightMap);
```

The values that I am sending are in the range 900.0f to 1590.0f.  But this gets completely clamped out to 1.0f as it loads into the `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

How do I preserve the values from being clamped to [0,1].  How should I modify the glTexImage2D() function to get this achieved?

P.S I know the sampler works fine because when I divide the values by 1500.0f and upload it to GPU and scale it in the shader, I get the proper height map structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should always use a [sized internal format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format) (that's the third parameter of `glTexImage*`). `GL_RED` leaves too much up to the implementation.

Second, you are trying to store and use floating-point data. So you need to choose a floating-point internal format, rather than a normalized integer one. If the internal format's size doesn't end in `F`, then it's not storing floating-point values. `GL_R32F` would be appropriate.